# User passes Auth::attempt(); Fails Auth::check('user')

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I'm working with an old copy of a client's database and making the new Laravel app work with its existing users.

I was building and testing with my User model using the '`users`' table, but I'm trying to hook it up to the '`auth_user`' table. After the changes, my new users are being created correctly. The login is a problem though. The users are passing `Auth::attempt($credentials) as expected`, but failing when

In my LoginController...

```
// post to /login

public function login() {

    $input = Request::all();

    // Log the user in
    if (Auth::attempt(['email'=>$input['username'], 'password'=>$input['password']])) {//Auth::attempt(Auth::attempt("admin", ['email' => $input['username'], 'password' => $input['password'], 'active' => 1])) { 
        // the user is now authenticated.
        return Redirect::to('/welcome')->with('message', 'Successfully authenticated');
    }
         return Redirect::to('/')
            ->with('message', 'Login Failed: Your Login Credentials Are Invalid');
    }
}
```

I'm definitely passing the `Auth::attempt(...)`, but I don't think my session is being set for that user. After the redirect to /welcome, I fail the `Auth::check('user')`

```
public function welcome() {
    if (!Auth::check('user')) return Redirect::to('/'); 

    // ... Top secret stuff (no returns or redirects though)

    return view('user.welcome', [                                   
                                'user' => Auth::user()
                                // ...
                                ]);
}
```

This redirects back to my login controller.

The kicker is this was all working when I was using my `'users'` table instead of `'auth_user'`.

`Users` uses `id` as the primary key, `Auth_user` uses `'uid'` as the primary key. I'd love to change the `uid` to be `id`, but I have to reuse a scary number of MYSQL stored procedures that I can't change.

**Relevant models:**

User.php:

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                    AuthorizableContract,
                                    CanResetPasswordContract
{

    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

    public function rules($scenario = null, $id = null) {
        $rules = [];

        switch($scenario) {
            case 'userAdd':
                $rules = [
                    'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6'
                ];
                break;
            case 'passwordChange':
                $rules = [
                    'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6'
                ];
                break;
        }

        return $rules;
    }

    public function isValid($scenario = null) {
        $validation = User::make($this->attributes, User::rules($scenario));

        if($validation->passes()) return true;

        $this->errors = $validation->messages();
        return false;
    }


    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'auth_user';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['username', 'name', 'password', 'email', 'expire', 'active', 'organization','role'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    protected $primaryKey = 'uid';
}
```

Auth.php (for multiple user types -- I know, I'd rather use roles instead of separate models too)

```
<?php

return [

    'multi' => [
        'user' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model'  => App\User::class,
            'table'  => 'auth_user'
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model'  => App\Admin::class,
            'table'  => 'auth_admin'
        ]
     ],

];
```

I think I covered all my bases for the primary key change, but I can't get the model to pass `Auth::check()`. Can someone with more Laravel experience *illuminate* what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Edited to clear up ambiguity of `auth_user` or `auth_users`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete fix. I still can't find anything to tell Laravel/Guard not to look at the ID column, so I bandaided it by adding an ID column and `$user->id = $user->uid;`. I'm not proud of this, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

In your User.php Script you need to place this code and this code make the table to login check.

```
protected $table='auth_users';
```

In your User.php code place that protected table code in initial stage( after the class function).

Comment: Thanks Sankar, but sadly it's already in my `User.php` script.